# Transactions rollbacked - can you find the text of the SQL command ?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

After a overflow of our LOG file we had some troubles and we restarted the server.

During startup, the database was automatically recovered. Now in the event protocol, there is this entry: "event 3407 - 1 transactions rolled back in database"

Is it possible to find out which transaction this exactly has been ?

Comment: FYI: Transactions are rolled-back in this circumstance because they are incomplete in the applied log files.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: is it possible that this is a transaction which has already been committed? Or can it only be a transaction which has not been committed?

Comment: AFAIK it can only be a transaction that was not committed *in the logs that you have applied* during the recovery.  In a recovery/roll-forward from backups, any transactions that were committed *after* the last applied log backup, would also be rolled-back.  However, automatic recovery's are usually done with the active log file (and not from backups), which should preclude any such problem.

Comment: @RBarryYoung OK! So all those previous transactions, which have been COMMITTED SUCCESSFULLY, should be fully okay ?

Comment: Yes.  This is one of the things that a DBMS like SQL Server (Or Orcale, etc...) is supposed to do for you: provide the highest level of data reliability and recovery that is practically possible.  Unless you lose your disk(s), you should never lose any committed data.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Thank you, that makes me very confident :-) - one last question, if you don't mind: If the database is set to autocommit, and if I call a stored procedure from a C# Client, and if the SP does not throw an error, than I can assume the procedure has committed ?

Comment: Yes, but ***only*** if the C# client code and the SP SQL code are written correctly.  I have seen a *lot* of code (both SQL and client) that did not catch and report errors correctly.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Do you probably have an example of good vs bad code ?

Answer (score 1):

I have been using APex sql log http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.asp and fn_dblog undocumented function for this purpose.